# How can i convert big (80k+lines) html files to pdf with dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I have some problems with converting big HTML files (+-80K lines) to a pdf.
I also have tried to split the files in to pieces, and merge them in the end.
Did this for the HTML and also for the PDFs, but even then i receive the memory exhausted error.

When i write the separate pdf files, i do clear the objects that writes them.
But even then the memory get pilled up with 'finished' data, so i think the problem is a memory leak in the dompdf library.

The library is used trough the Laravel framework, and is using version 0.6.1 because a vendor library need this version.
We have tried to update it to the latest version, but then that specific library will fail.

So my basically there are 2 questions.

1: How can we solve the memory problem, so large files (or splitted ones) could be handled without any problem. And not with changing the php_ini settings.

2: Is it possible to override the vendor library version in composer, so we can install the latest version. Without having issues that the vendor files are eddited also? Or is there any way to run 2 different versions in composer, so both keep working fine?

Hope someone got the answer to this, have spend about 2,5 for finding a fix to this... but sadly... nothing useful came out.

Edit;
Sample of what we are doing ( when using smaller files );

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    $htmlFileContents = ....; // Shorten it, but contains the html.
    $dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_option('chroot', storage_path('exports'));
    //$dompdf->load_html_file($file); * Should use even more memory
    $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->load_html($htmlFileContents);
    @$dompdf->render();    
   \File::put($tempFile, $dompdf->output());
   unset($dompdf);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure if it is the memory exhaust issue or execution time exhaust issue?

Comment: Have you tried any other libraries? dompdf might not be the best one for your use case.

Comment: Hello @HimanshuUpadhyay i have debugged it, and also logged the memory & execution time. And i am sure it is a memory problem, a colleague came to the same conclusion when he wanted to validate my finding.

Comment: @da39a3ee There are not a lot of (plain) HTML to PDF converters, i have looked for other ones. But everyone points us to the dompdf library, besides this is also used in other parts of our application and it works fine there ( much smaller files to convert ).

Comment: @PeterB., give my suggestions a try. Checkout my answer. I hope you will get the solution.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay already did, and still throws the same problem. 
But the amount of files extended by 2 extra written pdfs, so that does not make a lot of sense i guess..

But thanks for sharing the idea ;-)!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change settings in php.ini file then you can change the values runtime using `ini_set('parametername','value');` which will be affected to the project only not the whole php on server.

If its due to limitation of max execution time, then you can set it to be unlimited with `set_time_limit(0);` OR `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`
But if it is due to memory exhaust, use `ini_set('memory_limit',3000M);`

But keep in mind that set_time_limit(0) won't be honored if your script tkes time to execute external commands via system() or exec()/shell_exec() functions as stated in the doc. Also safe_mode must be off if you're PHP <= 5.3

Comment: Why have those settings if you are going to override them willy-nilly?

Comment: The problem is not the time limit, we have already set a time limit and it comes not even close to that limit.

I have tried to change the memory limit, but even then it will throw a memory exhausted error. I think it is weird, that when you clear a object/memory part, it still keeps appending data to the same script. 
For example; If i use a writer to write 1gb and clear it. It should start with the new clean writer for the next file. But it just keeps growing from the previous writer.

Comment: I also gave an example in the start post what we do with smaller files.
Keep in mind, it's just to give you an impression.